# Stores items distribution in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, bin-packing

Please help to resolve the following issue in sql:

There are 2 tables:

- Crates - which contains the current number of items in a crate
- Stores_demand - which contains the quantity of each item required in each store.

```
create table stores_demand
(sku    varchar(15),
store1  int,
store2  int,
store3  int,
store4  int,
store5  int,
store6  int,
store7  int,
store8  int,
store9  int,
store10 int,
demand int);


INSERT INTO stores_demand
values
('A100000219003',20,20, 20, 20, 0,20,15,20,0,0,135),
('A500000001928',20,20,20,20,16,0,0,0,0,0,96),
('A500000003308',20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,200),
('A500000006249',10,10,10,10,10,12,8,10,8,0,88),
('A500000007035',10,10,10,10,10,10,8,7,0,0,75),
('A500000007704',10,10,10,10,10,12,8,10,8,7,95),
('A500000008759',10,10,10,10,10,12,8,10,8,5,93),
('A500000008849',20,20,20,20,10,0,0,0,0,0,90),
('A500000009363',20,20,20,20,20,20,0,15,2,0,137),
('A500000010308',10,10,10,10,10,10,8,10,8,7,93),
('A500000010309',10,10,10,10,10,10,8,10,8,7,93),
('A500000011062',20,20,20,20,11,0,0,0,0,0,91),
('A500000011362',10,10,10,10,10,12,8,10,8,7,95),
('A500000011993',10,10,10,10,10,12,8,10,8,0,88),
('A500000012153',10,10,10,10,10,12,8,10,8,0,88),
('A500000014325',10,10,10,10,10,12,8,10,8,0,88),
('A500000014701',20,20,20,20,0,20,0,0,10,0,110),
('A500000014702',20,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23);


create table crates  
(sku    varchar(15),
crate_id varchar(30),   
total_quantity int);


INSERT INTO crates
values
('A100000219003','SH20000217-75',40),
('A100000219003','SH20000217-78',40),
('A100000219003','SH20000217-79',40),
('A100000219003','SH20000217-83',40),
('A100000219003','SH20000217-84',42),
('A100000219003','SH20000217-85',42),
('A100000219003','SH20000217-88',43),
('A100000219003','SH20000218-88',40),
('A100000219003','SH20000267-57',45),
('A500000001928','35WR21010117',32),
('A500000001928','SH20000141-16',64),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-159',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-160',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-161',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-162',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-163',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-164',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-165',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-166',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-167',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-168',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-169',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-170',30),
('A500000003308','SH20000234-172',29),
('A500000006249','102WR20019824',50),
('A500000006249','99WR20019824',50),
('A500000007035','72WR20019824',75),
('A500000007704','15WR21000780',130),
('A500000008759','107WR21007704',40),
('A500000008759','SH21000047-87',53),
('A500000008849','201WR21001888',20),
('A500000008849','202WR21001888',20),
('A500000008849','203WR21001888',20),
('A500000008849','204WR21001888',10),
('A500000008849','63WR21011733',20),
('A500000009363','SH20000141-14',80),
('A500000009363','SH20000141-15',37),
('A500000009363','SH20000141-16',20),
('A500000010308','64WR21010979',220),
('A500000010309','35WR21010979',220),
('A500000011062','50WR21008778',5),
('A500000011062','52WR21008778',25),
('A500000011062','6WR21014685',8),
('A500000011062','SH20000141-24',53),
('A500000011362','138WR21010218',100),
('A500000011993','19WR21014310',100),
('A500000012153','70WR20019824',250),
('A500000014325','30WR21000780',140),
('A500000014325','31WR21000780',110),
('A500000014701','126WR21008778',90),
('A500000014701','28WR21010117',24),
('A500000014702','31WR21010117',23);
```

Need to create a table that divide quantities over stores by crates size and demand limit and returns the amount per store and the crate number if needed to use (leftovers from an opened crate will be used as extra, no need to open the next crate if the quantity satisfies all stores).
Example:
Demand: 200
Number of stores: 10
Each store demand: 20
Sku: A12345

[division/packing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxLNj.png)

As seen above, each store requires 20 units, there are 10 stores, demand is 200 per sku A12345, each crate holds different quantity in it, column “get_crate” returns the crate number if needed to withdraw from the warehouse. If not, return NULL.

Comment: I suspect that you could simplify this problem to make it more understandable.  Perhaps only one store?  Or two stores?  I don't understand why stores are in *columns* rather than in separate rows.

Comment: This is how the existing scheme the customer has and I need to work with it and resolve the issue. 
I agree that I could reduce the number of stores to 3-4 to make more understandable. Thank you for your comment.